# Creating a list of files and separate the extension

Tags: python

So, in the folder INFACT, I have the following files(and many more with the same extensions):

```
BFDRYCKSE.ad
BFDRYCKSE.txt
BFFALIV2SE.ad
BFFALIV2SE.txt
```

I need to zip those files according to the filename, but only those mentioned above. My final result should be:

```
BFDRYCKSE.zip, contains(BFDRYCKSE.ad, BFDRYCKSE.txt)
BFFALIV2SE.zip, contains(BFFALIV2SE.ad BFFALIV2SE.txt)
```

Here's my code:

```
import os
import glob
import zipfile
setfile = r'C:\Users\vijo9001\Desktop\Infact'
myset = [
        "BFBRODSE",
        "BFDRYCKSE",
        "BFFALIV2SE",
        "BFFALIVSSE",
        "BFFRYSTSE",
        "BFHUSHA1SE",
        "BFHUSHA2SE",
        "BFHUSHALSE",
        "BFKONFEKSE",
        "BFKROPPVSE",
        "BFKROPP2SE",
        "BFLIV2SE",
        "BFLIVSSE",
        "BFMAKEUPSE",
        "BFMEJERISE",
        "BFTOBAKSE"
    ]
os.chdir(setfile)
list_of_lists = []
for i, pattern in enumerate(myset):
     list_of_files = glob.glob(r'*{pattern}*'.format(pattern=myset[i]))
     list_of_lists.append(list_of_files)
     n = 0
     file = os.path.splitext(list_of_files[0])[0]
     with zipfile.ZipFile(file + '.zip', 'w') as myzip:
          for f in list_of_files:
               myzip.write(f, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

I keep getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vijo9001/Desktop/Retailers Check/aaa.py", line 29, in <module>
    file = os.path.splitext(list_of_files[0])[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why is that?

Comment: I would assume `list_of_files` is empty when you try to access it?

Comment: It's not: 
[]
['BFDRYCKSE.ad', 'BFDRYCKSE.txt']
['BFFALIV2SE.ad', 'BFFALIV2SE.txt']
[]
[]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use an enumerator to access your list elements.

Your problem statement says that you want each zipfile to have the same basename as the .ad and .txt files which it should contain. With that in mind I'd try something along these lines instead

```
for basename in myset:
    filelist = glob.glob(r'*{pattern}*'.format(basename))
    with zipfile.ZipFile(basename + '.zip', 'w') as myzip:
      for f in filelist:
           myzip.write(f, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks  a lot for the help, however, your code doesn't seem to work since 'pattern' is not specified...

Comment: If you replace {pattern} with {basename} then I expect it to work.

Comment: I also don't expect people to copy+paste a "something along these lines" - that text _should_ be taken as an example collection of pseudocode to keep in mind while implementing the solution

Answer (score 0):

My solution is without defining set names:

=^..^=

```
import os
import zipfile

# get all files from directory
files_list = os.listdir(".")

# collect valid files
files_to_pack = []
for item in files_list:
    try:
        file_name, file_extension = item.split('.')
        if file_extension == 'ad' or file_extension == 'txt':
            files_to_pack.append(item)
    except:
        pass

# sort and pair files
sorted_files = sorted(files_to_pack)
pairs_files = [sorted_files[i:2+i] for i in range(0,len(sorted_files),2)]

# zip paired files
for item in pairs_files:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(item[0].split('.')[0] + '.zip', 'w') as myzip:
        myzip.write(item[0])
        myzip.write(item[1])
        myzip.close()
```

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, the thing is, not defining a set will cause all the files that match those file extensions to be zipped, I have thousands of those... I want specifically the `basenames` in `my_set` to be zipped :(

Comment: @JoãoVieira according to you example description the program finds pairs of 2 files and zip them to the folder with files name.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to add that in that folder there are many more files such as 

`BFDAAA.ad
BFDAAA.txt
BFFASE.ad
BFFASE.txt`

And many more... I don't want those to be zipped, it would take ages. Anyway, it's my fault I didn't specify it, I'll correct it :)